# Silverlight 3 Combobox Ui Virtualisation

Tags: silverlight-3.0, combobox, virtualization

I have added UI Virualisation to my combobox with 1000 items in it.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

The scrolling is now superfast :-) but the initial "open" is still really slow (2-3 seconds)

Is there a way to improve this opening time? My data is already bound so i assume this is a UI issue.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to set the ComboBox to Visibility=Collapsed, then bind/fill the Combobox and set the Visibility back to visible.

Background: as far as i know the insert operation also does a refresh/dedraw of the ui, so you have a 1000 refresh, but you dont see it.

regards
Christoph